# In Azure IoT Hub, how can I find daily quota usage (Device to Cloud Telemetry) used by each device IDs?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I saw these metrics once when I tried to troubleshoot IoT Hub. But I cannot find the right place to initiate the query.

**In the troubleshoot, the result is like:**

IoT Hub daily quota breakdown by operation type for the day (24 hours) prior to midnight (00:00) UTC:...

Top 10 Device IDs by daily quota usage for the prior 24 hours:...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no built-in solution to track **single D2C (device-to-cloud) messages** in Azure IoT Hub on a daily basis.

You can leverage Azure Monitor for [Monitoring Azure IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/monitor-iot-hub) and [Distributed Tracing (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/monitor-iot-hub-reference#distributed-tracing-preview). To fully enable these logs, client-side code must be updated by following [Analyze and diagnose IoT applications end-to-end with IoT Hub distributed tracing (preview).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-distributed-tracing) Then you can look at [IoT Hub D2C (device-to-cloud) logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/monitor-iot-hub-reference#iot-hub-d2c-device-to-cloud-logs) and write your logic to measure the number of messages\size to understand the quota usage per device.